Typescript: issue setting undefined to conditional types
The issue I am facing is incorrect typing returned from calling getShape function. The returned Object[varName] value can also be undefined, but the type returned doesn't state that it can also be undefined. It just states it is a Circle type if the parameter is circle and Square when my parameter is square. What am I missing here:
Types:
export type TShape=  'circle' | 'square'

export type TShapes<T> =
    T extends "circle" ? Circle | undefined :
    T extends "square" ? Square | undefined :        
    never;

Then my function
  protected static getShape<T extends TShape>(varName: T): TShapes<T> | undefined {
    return Object[varName]
  }


Please [edit] the code so it's a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing. Right now there are a bunch of undeclared types and an excerpt of a class, so in my IDE it's all errors, none of which you seem to be asking about. And please make sure to explicitly state exactly what your problem/question is, since it's not clear what you're asking about. It should ideally jump out at us when we look at it in an IDE (is there an error you get but don't expect? the opposite? etc? what, specifically?)

updated for clarification

Hmm, I still see errors. What's Circle? What's Square? What's Object? And what exactly is the problem? I can't see it. A [mre] would mean I copy and paste into my IDE and... wait, I'm just repeating myself. I see undefined all over your examples. Are you saying that somewhere undefined has been removed? Is this just a --strictNullChecks question disguised as a conditional type question? Please help us out by making a real [mre].
